# Spark streaming null pointer exception in yarn-client mode

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

Can anyone tell why the below code is throwing Null Pointer Execption in yarn-client mode whereas it runs fine on local mode.

```
val filters = args.takeRight(0)
val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("TwitterAnalyzer")
val ssc = new StreamingContext(sparkConf, Seconds(2))
val stream = TwitterUtils.createStream(ssc, None, filters)
val training = ssc.textFileStream("/user/hadoop/Training")
val tf = new HashingTF(numFeatures = 140)
val text = stream.filter(x => x.getLang() == "en" ).map( x =>  x.getText )
.filter(tweet => tweet != null).map(tweet => tf.transform(tweet.split(" ")))
```

**Exception is thrown at the last line of given code**

Here is the stacktrace of the error ( Program is the user class ) from yarn logs

> java.lang.NullPointerException  at
>   com.Program$$anonfun$5.apply(Program.scala:40)  at
>   com.Program$$anonfun$5.apply(Program.scala:40)  at
>   scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)  at
>   scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)  at
>   scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.next(Iterator.scala:312)  at
>   scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)  at
>   scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)  at
>   scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:48)
>   at
>   scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:103)
>   at
>   scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
>   at
>   scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:273) 
>   at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.to(Iterator.scala:1157)  at
>   scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:265)
>   at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toBuffer(Iterator.scala:1157)  at
>   scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:252)
>   at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toArray(Iterator.scala:1157)  at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$take$1$$anonfun$28.apply(RDD.scala:1328)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$take$1$$anonfun$28.apply(RDD.scala:1328)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1858)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1858)
>   at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66) 
>   at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)  at
>   org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214) 
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: what's `Program` line 40?

Comment: val text = stream.filter(x => x.getLang() == "en" ).map( x =>  x.getText )
.filter(tweet => tweet != null).map(tweet => tf.transform(tweet.split(" ")))

Comment: do you want to check the output of your `val stream` and see if all your filters are not resulting in empty RDDs? for example "en" might be "EN" when running with Yarn.

Comment: x => x.getLang() == "en" in this x is an object of twitter4j.Status so i dont think that "en" or "EN" will make any difference when run on yarn or local mode

Comment: well, you are getting the null pointer exception probably because one of your filter resulted in an empty Array, or your input is empty?

Comment: can you suggest where can i put null checks ? i have already tried

Comment: I would suggest just breaking this line into sections, and output each section to see which step is failing, so first make sure your input `stream` is not empty, next check the first filter, next check the getText is not returning all nulls.

Comment: i followed your suggestion and found that the exception is thrown by the transform method when we do tf.transform(tweet.split(" ")) even when tweet.split(" ") returns an Array[String] which is not empty . In the example provided by official spark they are using the transform method similarly . Any more suggestions ?

Comment: Yes, tf.transform requires each tweet.split(" ") to be not empty, so you need to make sure that all (every line) your tweet.split(" ") returns something that is not empty. You can add a filter before passing tweet to the tf.transform function. Something like tweet.filter(x=>(x.split(" ").size > 0)) should do it.